# Sending Message from C# tool to android emulator in android Studio

Tags: android, c#, shell-scripting, android-emulator

I am currently working in android studio. I came across a problem where my application inside android emulator needs to get some information(like string msg, or integer etc) through an external tool(tool may be any technology C#, etc).

So is it possible for me to get some information/message from external c# tool.?

if yes, please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to initiate communication from the Android emulator is to issue an HTTP(S) request. On a lower level, a TCP connection via sockets will work as well.

That means the C# tool needs to *listen* to those calls. It might already be able to (for example, if it's an ASP.NET application); otherwise, it'll need to implement something like an [`HttpListener`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) or a [`Socket`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-server-socket-example); MSDN has some fine examples on that. There is no simple framework or library to do this; you'll need to do some programming as well.

If you don't control the external tool, this will be difficult, but then it's simply a too broad question to be answered.